# Spell check program in python

Tags: python

> Exercise problem: "given a word list and a text file, spell check the
>   contents of the text file and print all (unique) words which aren't
>   found in the word list."

I didn't get solutions to the problem so can somebody tell me how I went and what the correct answer should be?:

As a disclaimer none of this parses in my python console...

My attempt:

---

```
a=list[....,.....,....,whatever goes here,...]

data = open(C:\Documents and Settings\bhaa\Desktop\blablabla.txt).read()          

#I'm aware that something is wrong here since I get an error when I use it.....when I just write blablabla.txt it says that it can't find the thing. Is this function only gonna work if I'm working off the online IVLE program where all those files are automatically linked to the console or how would I do things from python without logging into the online IVLE?

    for words in data:

        for words not in a

            print words

wrong = words not in a

right = words in a

print="wrong spelling:" + "properly splled words:" + right
```

---

oh yeh...I'm very sure I've indented everything correctly but I don't know how to format my question here so that it doesn't come out as a block like it has. sorry.

What do you think?

Comment: Why don't you fix the syntax errors first? Do you not know how? I am having trouble seeing what your problem is. Is it with Python syntax or with the problem itself?

Comment: Is this _homework_, or just an exercise you're trying to solve? I ask mostly because of tagging.

Answer (score 2):

There are many things wrong with this code - I'm going to mark some of them below, but I strongly recommend that you read up on Python control flow constructs, comparison operators, and built-in data types.

```
a=list[....,.....,....,whatever goes here,...]

data = open(C:\Documents and Settings\bhaa\Desktop\blablabla.txt).read()          
# The filename needs to be a string value - put "C:\..." in quotes!

for words in data:
# data is a string - iterating over it will give you one letter
# per iteration, not one word

    for words not in a
    # aside from syntax (remember the colons!), remember what for means - it
    # executes its body once for every item in a collection. "not in a" is not a
    # collection of any kind!

        print words

wrong = words not in a
# this does not say what you think it says - "not in" is an operator which
# takes an arbitrary value on the left, and some collection on the right,
# and returns a single boolean value

right = words in a
# same as the previous line

print="wrong spelling:" + "properly splled words:" + right
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to iterate over, but why don't you just first iterate over your words (which are in the variable a I guess?) and then for every word in a you iterate over the wordlist and check whether or not that word is in the wordslist.

I won't paste code since it seems like homework to me (if so, please add the homework tag).

Btw the first argument to open() should be a string.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple really. Turn both lists into [sets](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) then take the [difference](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set.difference). Should take like 10 lines of code. You just have to figure out the syntax on your own ;) You aren't going to learn anything by having us write it for you.